# Sending with redux function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am making a project with an automatic response from a bot in the messenger. When sending a message, it is rendered, but an error pops up

SandBoxCode:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-messanger-middleware-xfsywn?file=/package.json

MessageField.js:

```
 static propTypes = {
        chatId: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        messages: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        chats: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        sendMessage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    };
 handleSendMessage = (message, sender) => {
        if (this.state.input.length > 0 || sender === 'bot') {
            this.props.sendMessage(message, sender);
        }
        if (sender === 'me') {
            this.setState({ input: '' });
        }
    };
render() {
        const { chatId, messages, chats } = this.props;
        const messageElements = chats[chatId].messageList.map((messageId, index) => (
            <Message
                key={ index }
//error         text={ messages[messageId].text }
                sender={ messages[messageId].sender }
            />));
```

chatReducer.js

```
import update from 'react-addons-update';
import { SEND_MESSAGE } from '../actions/messageActions';
import { ADD_CHAT } from "../actions/chatAction";
const initialStore = {
    chats: {
        1: {title: 'Чат 1', messageList: [1]},
        2: {title: 'Чат 2', messageList: [2]},
        3: {title: 'Чат 3', messageList: []},
    },user:{username:'gnehgo'}
};
export default function chatReducer(store = initialStore, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SEND_MESSAGE: {
            return update(store, {
                chats: { $merge: { [action.chatId]: {
                            title: store.chats[action.chatId].title,
                            messageList: [...store.chats[action.chatId].messageList,
                                action.messageId]
                        } } },
            });
        }
        case ADD_CHAT: {
            const chatId = Object.keys(store.chats).length + 1;
            return update(store, {
                chats: { $merge: {
                        [chatId]: {
                            title: action.title, messageList: []
                        } } },
            });
        }
        default:
            return store;
    }
}
```